# Is there any way to access many services from the same port?

Tags: networking, apache-http-server, port, domain-name

To clarify: I am running apache on port 80 of course. I am also running DynMap on the same server. Is there any way to make it so that I can access it through port 80, or do i simply have to open the port and type in domain.com:port to access it?

I am asking generally, not just for DynMap

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible by leveraging Virtual Hosts. Easiest setup in this case would be to let DynMap run on e.g. `localhost:8080` and setup Apache to reverse proxy to this "host" for a Virtual Host: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/ and http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html

NOTE that you need different *domains* in this case, but subdomains suffice.